# Terraform resource aws_batch_job_definition creation fails with data template_file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-batch

Trying to create an AWS Batch Job Definition via Terraform.

Json used in the data source `template_file`:

```
[
  {
    "command": "${docker_command}",
    "image": "${docker_image}",
    "resourceRequirements": [
      {
        "type": "MEMORY",
        "value": "${memory}"
      },
      {
        "type": "VCPU",
        "value": "${vcpu}"
      }
    ],
    "jobRoleArn": "${job_role_arn}",
    "volumes": [
      {
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/mnt/efs"
      },
      "name": "efs"
      }
    ],
    "mountPoints": [
      {
        "sourceVolume": "efs",
        "containerPath": "/mnt/efs",
        "readOnly": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Terraform code:

```
data "template_file" "dev_jd_template" {
  template = "${file("./data/job_definition.json")}"

  vars = {
    docker_command = "[python /app/data_migrator.py]"
    docker_image   = "python:3.9.9-slim-bullseye"
    memory         = 1024
    vcpu           = 1
    job_role_arn   = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/AWSBatchJobRole"
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "job_definition" {
  name                  = "dev-jd-3"
  type                  = "container"
  platform_capabilities = ["EC2"]
  container_properties  = "${data.template_file.dev_jd_template.rendered}"
}
```

Error:

```
AWS Batch Job container_properties is invalid: Error decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type batch.ContainerProperties
│
│   with aws_batch_job_definition.job_definition,
│   on jd.tf line 23, in resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "job_definition":
│   23:   container_properties  = "${data.template_file.dev_jd_template.rendered}"
```

If I pass the value for `container_properties` as `file("./data/job_definition.json")`, it works fine but as we have more than 1 `job_definitions`, we were hoping to use template.

I have also looked at a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047389/terraform-rejecting-json-template-file) but couldn't figure out what's wrong in my case.

TIA!

Comment: Usage here is rather unusual. Can you begin fixing this by updating to the use of the `templatefile` function and we can go from there?

Comment: Appreciate your comment. An example would be useful to better understand what exactly you're suggesting.

Comment: I think I have hit a similar error when quoting the values which should be numbers in JSON. For example, if you remove the quotes from `"${memory}"` and `"${cpu}"` it should work. There is probably some kind of validation of the JSON as it expects numbers and not strings for those parameters.

Comment: Wow, I answered the question, tested the code locally, and it's complaining still. Very interesting.

Comment: @MarkoE looking at the SO question I referred to in my post, I did try that already. Even tried to add (and remove) double quotes around memory and vcpu values in the data source but no luck.

Comment: I think I figured out what the issue is, now trying to find a solution.

Comment: @rock'nrolla please take a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while to realize where the issue is because it is not that obvious and the error is not of too much help. Now, looking at the example from the official documentation [1], here is where the catch is:

```
"command": ["ls", "-la"],
```

This is expected for the `command` argument. So it is actually a **list** of strings. In your question, you are using a string which looks like a list consisting of only one element:

```
"[python /app/data_migrator.py]"
```

The above would be a single line, a single string, not a list of strings as required by the `command` property. Additionally, this seems to be an edge case since you cannot pass a list of strings neither using `template_file` data source nor `templatefile` built-in function the way you have tried to.

With some amount of poking around and using an example from the Terraform docs [2], I have managed to get an output that you want. First, the change that needs to happen in the templated file:

```
${jsonencode({
    "command": [ for command in docker_command: command ],
    "image": docker_image,
    "resourceRequirements": [
        {
            "type": "MEMORY",
            "value": memory
        },
        {
            "type": "VCPU",
            "value": vcpu
        }
    ],
    "jobRoleArn": job_role_arn,
    "volumes": [
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "/mnt/efs"
            },
            "name": "efs"
        }
    ],
    "mountPoints": [
        {
            "sourceVolume": "efs",
            "containerPath": "/mnt/efs",
            "readOnly": false
        }
    ]
})}
```

This will replace **all** the placeholder values in the template with the values provided when calling the `templatefile` function. Note  that you actually **have to use double quotes** around values for CPU and memory because otherwise you get the following error:

> AWS Batch Job container_properties is invalid: Error decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field ResourceRequirement.ResourceRequirements.Value of type string

This is fine because the AWS docs say that those values are strings anyway [3].

Now that the template is fixed, here is how to use the `templatefile` built-in [4] function:

```
resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "job_definition" {
  name                  = "dev-jd-3"
  type                  = "container"
  platform_capabilities = ["EC2"]
  container_properties = templatefile("${path.root}/data/job_definition.json",
    {
      docker_command = ["python", "/app/data_migrator.py"]
      docker_image   = "python:3.9.9-slim-bullseye"
      memory         = "1024" # <----- quoted value!
      vcpu           = "1"    # <----- quoted value!
      job_role_arn   = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/AWSBatchJobRole"
  })
}
```

This should result in a plan like this:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_batch_job_definition.job_definition will be created
  + resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "job_definition" {
      + arn                   = (known after apply)
      + container_properties  = jsonencode(
            {
              + command              = [
                  + "python",
                  + "/app/data_migrator.py",
                ]
              + image                = "python:3.9.9-slim-bullseye"
              + jobRoleArn           = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/AWSBatchJobRole"
              + mountPoints          = [
                  + {
                      + containerPath = "/mnt/efs"
                      + readOnly      = false
                      + sourceVolume  = "efs"
                    },
                ]
              + resourceRequirements = [
                  + {
                      + type  = "MEMORY"
                      + value = "1024"
                    },
                  + {
                      + type  = "VCPU"
                      + value = "1"
                    },
                ]
              + volumes              = [
                  + {
                      + host = {
                          + sourcePath = "/mnt/efs"
                        }
                      + name = "efs"
                    },
                ]
            }
        )
      + id                    = (known after apply)
      + name                  = "dev-jd-3"
      + platform_capabilities = [
          + "EC2",
        ]
      + propagate_tags        = false
      + revision              = (known after apply)
      + tags_all              = (known after apply)
      + type                  = "container"
    }
```

I would also strongly recommend renaming the template file to use something like `job_definition.json.tftpl` naming convention, as this is suggested in the documentation:

> `*.tftpl` is the recommended naming pattern to use for your template files. Terraform will not prevent you from using other names, but following this convention will help your editor understand the content and likely provide better editing experience as a result.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/batch_job_definition#example-usage

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile#generating-json-or-yaml-from-a-template

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_ResourceRequirement.html

[4] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile

Comment: Thanks a lot Marko. I realized the mistake in the `command` argument and was able to correct that but the next challenge as you pointed out correctly was list of strings where I was stuck now. As pointed out by Matt in his comment and the documentation of the `template_file` data source, I started looking at the `templatefile` function but I missed the trick with the for loop which you worked out pretty well. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to go step by step in the answer so someone else that might be reading in the future understands the thought process that lead to the solution.